# Programmatically Determine Tables/Other Objects Referenced in an Oracle Stored Procedure/Package

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Do anyone know of a way to find the tables/views/etc that are referenced in an Oracle stored procedure/package short of parsing it out?  (i.e. some sort of shortcut)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from user_dependencies where name='NAME_OF_YOUR_PROCEDURE';
```

is all you need.